How to make bottom navigation small

This is how my current bottom navigation bar is looking
In this I am not able to removing that extra padding which is being added below the texts
I tried removing all the padding but it doesn't work
Even when I try to reduce the layout height it starts overlapping with the icons
the current code for this bottom navigation bar is
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_error"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:itemPaddingBottom="0dp"
    app:itemPaddingTop="0dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

I tried removing all the padding and also tried by making the layout height to 56 dp but it still doesn't remove that extra padding below the text
